# Scraping data from Tableau chart with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tableau-api

I would like to scrape ownership data from the following website:

```
https://www.usnewsdeserts.com/states/california/#1536357227283-a4a9d6e4-ccf9
```

The code I use is the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re
import random
url = "https://public.tableau.com/vizql/w/TopOwnersCalifornia/v/Owners/bootstrapSession/sessions/5E565C4C5F7D462BBE8DFEE9246F846E-0:0"
header = random.choice(user_agent_list)
url = "https://public.tableau.com/vizql/w/TopOwnersCalifornia/v/Owners/bootstrapSession/sessions/5E565C4C5F7D462BBE8DFEE9246F846E-0:0"
header = random.choice(user_agent_list)
HEADERS = {"User-Agent": header}
params = {"stickySessionKey": {"dataserverPermissions":"44136fa355b3678a1146ad16f7e8649e94fb4fc21fe77e8310c060f61caaff8a"}}
r = requests.post(url, params=params, headers = HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")      
print(soup)
```

I get:

```
<br/>
2020-12-12 12:41:46.829
(X9S6ik90vQizHF9Qa-S@CwAAAUk,0:0)
```

How can I get this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a [tableau scraper library](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping) to extract the data from Tableau worksheets. You just need to find the tableau URL in the network tab of developer tools, in this case :

```
GET https://public.tableau.com/views/NewspapersByCountyCalifornia/Newspaperbycounty
```

You can extract the data with the following code :

```
from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS

url = "https://public.tableau.com/views/NewspapersByCountyCalifornia/Newspaperbycounty"

ts = TS()
ts.loads(url)
dashboard = ts.getDashboard()

for t in dashboard.worksheets:
    #show worksheet name
    print(f"WORKSHEET NAME : {t.name}")
    #show dataframe for this worksheet
    print(t.data)
```

[run in this repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/TableauScrapeNewspaper)